# TypeError: this.root_ is null

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular8

Using material https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web/tree/master/packages/mdc-drawer
trying to get it working Iget

I use:

```
  <aside class="mdc-drawer mdc-drawer--dismissible">
  <div class="mdc-drawer__content">
    <nav class="mdc-list">
      <a class="mdc-list-item mdc-list-item--activated" href="#" aria-current="page">
        <i class="material-icons mdc-list-item__graphic" aria-hidden="true">inbox</i>
        <span class="mdc-list-item__text">Inbox</span>
      </a>
      <a class="mdc-list-item" href="#">
        <i class="material-icons mdc-list-item__graphic" aria-hidden="true">send</i>
        <span class="mdc-list-item__text">Outgoing</span>
      </a>
      <a class="mdc-list-item" href="#">
        <i class="material-icons mdc-list-item__graphic" aria-hidden="true">drafts</i>
        <span class="mdc-list-item__text">Drafts</span>
      </a>
    </nav>
  </div>
</aside>

<div class="mdc-drawer-app-content">
  App Content
</div>
```

As soon, as I import this:

```
import {MDCList} from "@material/list";
const list = MDCList.attachTo(document.querySelector('.mdc-list'));
list.wrapFocus = true;
```

or this

```
import {MDCDrawer} from "@material/drawer";
const drawer = MDCDrawer.attachTo(document.querySelector('.mdc-drawer'));
```

Like written in the tutorial, I get this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/G6KgT.jpg

Comment: Did you have any luck with this?

Answer (score 0):

The material-components Javascript code uses `import` statements. This is a newer Javascript feature and, although most web browsers now support it natively, you need to add `type="module"` to the `<script>` element in your HTML.

You haven't included your HTML in the question, but it should look something like:

```
<script type="module" src="./main.js">
```

Alternatively, you can tell `webpack` to use the `babel` plugin with the `preset-env` option to transpile the ES6 code into ES5 code that will work around the `import` statements.

More detail: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules